# Group by doesn't work (SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column)

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0 version

I have a `Result` table with columns of

```
id, playerId, groupId, position, timestamp
```

And I want to query a list of results on a specific player with unique groupId and position sorted in timestamp descending order. So within the same groupId, there could be multiple records of the same position, and I want to query only the latest record. So I think the key is to combine groupId and position for group by clause but I have no clue how to do that.

First, I tried...

```
SELECT * FROM Result
WHERE playerId = 15
GROUP BY groupId, position
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Got the following result.

```
> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
> clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Result.id' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

So I tried...

```
SELECT *
FROM Result
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM Result
    WHERE playerId = '15'
    GROUP BY groupId
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
);
```

Got the following result.

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| id   | playerId |  groupId | position | timestamp     | 
+------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| 2634 |     15   |      237 |        1 | 1583703228386 |
| 2628 |     15   |      237 |        2 | 1583690801160 |
| 2627 |     15   |      237 |        1 | 1583690798117 | 
| 2622 |     15   |      237 |        1 | 1583687601090 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----+-
```

As you can see, there're groupId 237 with multiple of position 1.
What I want is

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| id   | playerId |  groupId | position | timestamp     | 
+------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| 2634 |     15   |      237 |        1 | 1583703228386 |
| 2628 |     15   |      237 |        2 | 1583690801160 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----+-
```

How do I do that?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The first query was the better one, but the problem is MySQL doesn't know how to choose the id in the group. You can use an aggregated function of some kind, or even better you could not select the id at all.

Comment: Also, how did you choose the timestamp for group 237 and position 1?

Comment: providing a dataset to test would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Which record do you want if there are more than one with an id?

Comment: 'timestamp' represents the time the record was made. So in the query I've tried above, what I meant to do is to sort the records from latest to earliest and pick only the latest grouping by groupId and position.

Comment: Say I have a list of data set in format of  (groupId, position) such as (237, 0), (237, 1), (238, 0), (238, 0), (238, 1), I want the result to be (237, 0), (237, 1), (238, 0), (238, 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
SELECT t.id, t.playerId, t.groupId, t.position, t.timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY timestamp desc) rn
  FROM Result
  WHERE playerId = '15'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

If there are multiple different `groupId`s for `playerId = '15'` and you want 1 row for each combination of `groupId, position` then:

```
SELECT t.id, t.playerId, t.groupId, t.position, t.timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groupId, position ORDER BY timestamp desc) rn
  FROM Result
  WHERE playerId = '15'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Your second script solved my problem. Had to add one more order by at the end to sort in descending order. SELECT t.id, t.userId, t.circleId, t.position, t.timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY circleId, position ORDER BY timestamp desc) rn
  FROM Transaction
  WHERE userId = '15'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that timestamps are unique in your case, I would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM 
(SELECT groupId, position, MAX(timestamp) as lastTimestamp
FROM Result
GROUP BY groupId, position) as lastResults
LEFT JOIN Result r
ON lastResults.groupId = r.groupId 
AND lastResults.position = r.position
AND lastResults.lastTimestamp = r.timestamp;
```

The trick here is to first identify the unique composite keys for the data you need (`groupId`, `position`, `MAX(timestamp)`) and then select the data based on those keys.

If timestamps are not unique, then you have to decide which row to select based on whatever business requirements you have. My query in that case will return duplicate rows.

Comment: I just tested this script and confirmed it worked. Very nice! Thank you! But seems like I can accept only one answer. I gave it to the answer above. Sorry about that.

Comment: @KoreanDude No problem, my answer might help someone else later.